# Hide column header in ui-grid AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid for displaying data. I want to hide the column header. Is there any property for this cause? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you wish to hide the header for a particular column or the entire header row, so it is just the data rows? Also, does "hide" mean "show as blank with no text" or "completely hide from view"?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to hide the entire header row (completely hide from the view)

Comment: It worked :) There was an option hideHeader:true which I set during the ui-grid specification. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you add that as an answer to your own question and accept it, then. That will prevent this question from showing up as unanswered, and allow other people to find the answer to your question quicker than you did.

Answer (score 11):

Based on [Angular-ui Change log](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

#### Breaking Changes

The `hideHeader` option has been changed to `showHeader`

To migrate, change your code from the following:

`hideHeader: true`

To:

`showHeader: false`

Comment: neither showHeader or hideHeader worked for me version:3.2.9. using @Rob Sedgwick approach with  the 'blank' header template worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

neither showHeader nor hideHeader did anything for me. I used this:

```
headerCellTemplate: '<div></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

**This has been changed to `showHeader:false` in latest version of `ui-grid`  `(3.1.1)`**